# Is there a way to control CustomElementRegistry and name other than "dom-module"

Tags: polymer, web-component, lit-element

We are using LitElement to build custom components (not public). Let's call it CompA and CompB. We are publishing the packages using CDN.

We use it in HTML via Script tag of type module. And each component works fine when it is the only component on the page. The moment we import CompA and CompB on the same page, we have a problem.

Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': the name "dom-module" has already been used with this registry

I know the problem is arising because of use of similar set of UI components across CompA and CompB. Probably paper-input, paper-button etc.

Is there a way to avoid this error by have better control over naming CustomElementRegistry and name other than "dom-module" when building your components using LitElement.

Update: I think I wasn't clear enough when asking so I have updated the question.

Comment: Provide your code for more inputs of the community

Comment: If you are naming all of your component "dom-module" then you have a problem. If not then post your code so we can figure it out.

Comment: @walker I have faced the same, check the versions in package.json, one or more element is an old version. update all. It should be solved.

Comment: This is propably some dependency issue. try to clear package.json and install all dependencies again to get the newest versions.

Comment: Tip: use polymer serve to ensure everything is not conflicting + don't use multiple symlinks

Comment: Running into a similar issue, though we are using Svelte to push out custom-elements:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63678685/how-to-handle-svelte-custom-element-cross-dependencies-and-failed-to-execute-d
Curious if the answer below can in some way apply to our problem...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this problem is a really good reason for component libraries *to leave component registration up to the consuming application*

in my component libraries, i offer a simple function called `registerComponents`

```
function dashify(camel) {
  return camel.replace(/([a-zA-Z])(?=[A-Z])/g, '$1-').toLowerCase()
}

export function registerComponents(components) {
  for (const componentName of Object.keys(components))
    customElements.define(dashify(componentName), components[componentName])
}
```

this makes it really easy for consumers to register components

the function simply converts the component names from camel case to dashed names (eg `ShopperCart` becomes `shopper-cart`)

my component libraries provide a convenience module called `register-all.js`, which performs all the registrations similarly to how a consumer might if they do this manually

```
import {ShopperCart} from "./components/shopper-cart.js"
import {ShopperButton} from "./components/shopper-button.js"
import {ShopperProduct} from "./components/shopper-product.js"
import {ShopperCollection} from "./components/shopper-collection.js"

import {registerComponents} from "./toolbox/register-components.js"

registerComponents({
  ShopperCart,
  ShopperCollection,
  ShopperButton,
  ShopperProduct
})
```

with this approach, it's really easy to rename components

```
registerComponents({
  MyCart: ShopperCart
})
```

of course, in this case, a consumer can choose to simply import the convenient `register-all.js` to stick with the standard names

```
import "shopper/dist/register-all.js"
```

so to be clear, it's a bad pattern to use a `customElements.define` call within each component module, because we want to allow consumers some flexibility

you don't have to use or offer the handy `registerComponents` i suggest, but the important thing is that the consumer gets to choose how registration is handled

cheers,  chase

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I like your `registerComponents` Idea to pass an object of components in it and I come up a idea like to pass a object as `{ class: ShopperCart, componentName: "shoping-cart"}`.

Answer (score 0):

Regards the API, no !

it is only possible to read the customElementRegistry but there is no provided function to update it or manipulate it after it was registration. It would also be a no sense to do it.

By the way, you should not use dom-module since it is reserved.

Comment: Thanks for answering. The component that is created using LitElement is using the dom-module. Not having issues when using one component. But when using 2 separate components , getting this error.

Answer (score -1):

Once a component is registered. you cannot override or re-register an element with the same name. instead you can use multiple instance of the same component or extend the existing one.